# How can I retain the state of pages opened in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have two pages demo1.html and demo2.html. I want to open both of these in an iframe using JavaScript/Jquery. Demo1.html has some content boxes with a button in them and demo2.html has some multi-select drop-downs in it.Now I have to implement two different scenarios given this situation.

1- When I click on any of the button in demo1.html, I want to open demo2.html in the iframe with some options selected based on the id/class of the button in demo1.

2- When I made some selections in the demo2 page, I want them to be there even if I open demo1 again.

Sample code is given below.I haven't found any luck so far.Any ideas how can I do that? thanks

Index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>index</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .tabConWrap {
    width:98%;    
    position:relative;
    padding-top:28px;
    margin:10px auto 30px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #39f;
    text-align:left;
}
.tabs {
    width:auto;
    height:28px;
    margin:0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px;
}
.tabs li {    
    margin:0px 2px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    display:inline;
    font:bold 12px Arial,Sans-Serif;
}
.tabs li a {
    background-color:#39f; 
    color:white;
    padding:7px 10px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom:none;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
.tabs .currentTab {
    background-color:white; 
    color:#999;
    position:relative;
    z-index:7;
}
.tabContainer {
    padding:10px;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-3px;
    z-index:2;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.tabContainer iframe {
    border:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

h2#loading {
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font:bold 11px Arial,Sans-Serif;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    padding:5px 0px;
    background-color:#BC151A;
    color:white;    
}

  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var tabs = $('.tabs li a'),
      tabContents = $('div.tabContainer');

      tabs.eq(0).addClass('currentTab');

      tabs.click(function() {
          tabs.removeClass();
          $(this).addClass('currentTab');
          tabContents.animate({height:0}, 'slow')
              .find('iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
          // $('body').append('<h2 id="loading">Loading...</h2>');
          return false;
      });
      $('div.tabConWrap iframe').bind("load", function() {
          tabContents.animate({height:1000}, 'slow');
          $('h2#loading').remove();
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tabConWrap">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="demo1.html">demo1</a></li>
        <li><a href="demo2.html">demo2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tabContainer">
        <iframe name="myframe"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Demo1 Page:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>index</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .box1,.box2,.box3{
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      margin-left: 15px;
      display: inline-block
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box1">box1
    <button>button1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">box2
  <button>button2</button>
</div>
  <div class="box3">box3
  <button>button3</button>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Demo2 Page:

```
<html>
<body>

<div>
  <select name="cars" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</div>
<div>
  <select name="bike" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">honda</option>
    <option value="saab">yamaha</option>
    <option value="opel">Suzuki</option>
    <option value="audi">metro</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</div>
<div>
  <select name="random" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">abc</option>
    <option value="saab">def</option>
    <option value="opel">xyz</option>
    <option value="audi">www</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</div>



<p>Use ctrl+click to select multiple options</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post examples of what you have already tried - we are here to help, not to do the work for you

Comment: To do that easily (and much more) is basically why people invented JS frameworks like React.

Comment: You need to use some persistent storage e.g localStorage, IndexedDB or even cookie

Comment: @ChrisG `(and much more)` ya very much more... Using React for that would be like bring a gun to a pillow fight imho

Comment: @A.Wolff Sure, I'm not saying every trivial web app should be implemented using React. I'm just pointing out to the OP that this particular wheel has already been reinvented several times.

Comment: The simplest would be to write to localStorage and later read from it.